# AutoFilter two independent columns with criteria and display all rows contains that criteria

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

As you see on the above picture, I need to use AutoFilter to show rows contains specific value e.g `102`.
With Excel interface , I cannot use the criteria value `102` on Columns “B” & “C” on the same time. 
I want to maintain the sort and structure of my dataset. 
As a workaround, is it possible to show rows contains value `102` on Columns “B” & “C” and hide the other rows in between. 
In advance I am grateful for all your help.

```
Sub Filter_criteria()
 
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = ws.Range("A2:R" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
 
   If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter       'Set AutoFilter if not already set
 
  rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*102*", Operator:=xlAnd
 
End Sub
```

Comment: One option is to use a helper column. Otherwise a loop will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next adapted code. It firstly, apply a filter on the second column, then unhide rows if the third column contains criteria:

```
Sub Filter_criteria()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Const crit As String = "*102*"
         
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False      
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1:R" & ws.cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
          
    'place the first filter in second column:
    rng.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
         
    'unhide according to the third column, by iteration:
    For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
        If rng.cells(i, 3).Value Like crit Then rng.rows(i).Hidden = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

A second version follows somehow BibBen's suggestion. The code builds an array as result of B:B and C:C concatenation and drop its content after the last column (after R:R), then filter by it and clear at the end:

```
Sub evaluateConcat()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, rng As Range, arr
   Const crit As String = "*102*"
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
   lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   lastCol = ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set rng = ws.Range("A1:S" & lastR)
   
   'create an array as concatenation between columns B:B and C:C
   arr = Evaluate(ws.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Address & "&" & ws.Range("C2:C" & lastR).Address)

   With ws.cells(1, lastCol + 1)
        .Value = "ConcCol"      'header
        .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr 'drop the array content after the last column
   End With
   
   rng.AutoFilter field:=lastCol + 1, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlFilterValues  'filter by the above built column

   ws.Columns(lastCol + 1).ClearContents 'clear the content of the added column
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

A third version will iterate between the two columns keeping criteria, placed in an array and build a `Union` range (of not matching criteria) to be finally hidden:

```
    Sub FilterByTwoCols()
      Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, HdRng As Range
      Const crit As String = "*102*"
      
      Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
      ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'make all rows visible
      lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
      
      arr = ws.Range("B2:C" & lastR).Value2 'place the relevant columns in an array for faster iteration
      For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If Not arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) Like crit Then
                addToRange HdRng, ws.Range("A" & i + 1) 'make  a Union range of the rows NOT matching criteria...
            End If
      Next i
      If Not HdRng Is Nothing Then HdRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide not matching criteria rows.
End Sub

Private Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested both your codes. The first one works perfectly without problem in all cases and I am amazed with it’s speed (finished in 0.03 sec in 10k rows),
although it using normal loop.

Comment: The second code works correctly and also fast (finished in 0.04 sec), But there is an issue,
If `Columns("D:R")` are hidden (before run the code), I found that the entire column “D” has been cleared from its initial values and code time increased to (0,6 sec),
and strangely the final result of filtering is correct. Is it possible to eliminate the actual helper column and manipulate all values in memory ( using Array or Dictionary) ?

Comment: @Waleed 1. First variant is fast due to the fact that it does not use `Cells` iteration. Is uses the variable iteration and only reads the cell value. It (probably) can be faster if all rows to be unhidden will be placed in a `Union` range and unhide them at once. But hiding, unhiding does not take so long as rows deletion, when Excel needs to recalculate all references of the remaining cells. 2. I cannot imagine what's happening related to D:D content deletion. Are you sure that this is happening *after running the code*? Did you test it once more, placing dummy data in the respective col.?

Comment: @Waleed A Dictionary will be useless in such a case. Processing the existing range array and **building a `Union` range of the rows to be hidden** will work fast, only the actual hiding takes some time. It will be comparable in terms of speed with the second version. Standard Excel filter is optimized by Microsoft to be faster. That's why I used it for half of the job, in my first code version, and also for filtering the helper column. No time availability now, but I will play during the day with a version involving array processing to build a `Union` range and hide it at the end...

Comment: @Waleed Please, test the third version, designed as I mentioned above.

Comment: I am afraid that you forgot to show `addToRange` function on the provided answer

Comment: @Waleed Yup... I will copy it now. Added.

Comment: **Excellent**, now the third variant works perfectly and very fast (finished in 0.07 sec).
Actually , both of your answers are unique and the last one will be beneficial with heavy abnormal criteria filtering 

Comment: @Waleed It should be fast, but I would not count extremely on that 0,07 sec... For such a small time, if you repeat the test many times, it will return according to other open applications which use/load CPU... Anyhow, what is below a second should be considere very fast. :) Then, according to the estimated percentage of rows to be hide, the code can be adjusted to firstly hide all rows and then unhide only the necessary one (if less percentage than the hidden ones)...

Comment: Good Morning, Kindly (in your free time) can you help in this question and clarify why my trial of using `Custom View` is not reliable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182795/how-to-restore-show-visible-rows-before-applying-autofilter-plus-unhide-rows-on