# How to restore/show visible rows before applying AutoFilter, without using helper columns?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Regarding this question to apply AutoFilter in addition to unhide rows on conditions ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854747/autofilter-two-independent-columns-with-criteria-and-display-all-rows-contains-t)).
I have a difficulty to restore/show exactly the same rows before using this unusual approach of Autofilter. 
In fact, I am using autofilter sequentially two times. 
**Meaning**, I run autofilter and got some data, e.g **Autofilter(1)** 
And again I run autofilter (sure with different criteria) and I got a substract data, e.g **Autofilter(2)** 
My question, How after using Autofilter (2), to return back the same state after using Autofilter(1) ? 
I have created a `custom view` to capture the state of (visible rows,) at the end of code Autofilter(1) as the following:

```
Dim cv As CustomView
Set cv = ThisWorkbook.CustomViews.Add(ViewName:="Autofilter_1", RowColSettings:=True)
```

Then, after using Autofilter (2) , I restored that custom view(cv):

```
If Not cv Is Nothing Then cv.Show
```

I found out this method is not fully reliable, as some rows still not restored as visible.
The codes of both autofilters use the same logic, so this the code of autofilter(1)

```
Sub Filter_criteria()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Const crit As String = "*102*"
 
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False     
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1:R" & ws.cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
 
    'place the first filter in second column:
    rng.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
 
    'unhide according to the third column, by iteration:
    For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
        If rng.cells(i, 3).Value Like crit Then rng.rows(i).Hidden = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

At last, I am grateful for all your assistance.

Comment: I only played sometimes with such `CustomViews`. At least, that time Excel did not allow creating to such `CustomViews` if a single `Table` exists in the respective workbook and I did not consider that further experimenting should be interesting... In theory, showing such a `CustomView` all rows/columns should look like in the moment when it has been saved. In order to understand what you mean by "some rows still not restored as visible" you should show a reproductibile example. If between setting the view and showing it you modify cells value, it will show the new value, of course.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have sent the actual workbook to your email found on your profile

Comment: OK. I will try looking on it.

Comment: I sent back the workbook, which works as in should in my environment...

Comment: @FaneDuru , I tested the updated workbook, first thanks for your help.
I thought you will use array or Loop or any other method to preserve `numbers of the visible rows` (after Autofilter_1) and restore back، like you did on the linked question

Comment: I could do that, but your question was not about an alternative solution... At least, this is what I understood. I only tried understanding why you said that "some rows still not restored as visible" and I discovered that if you do not have strange previous filtering the `CustomView` works as it should. I mean exactly returning the visibility of rows/columns from the moment when it has been set. **Doesn't the sent back workbook behave correctly, from this point of view**? Then you cannot keep discontinuous ranges in an array. But markers of the respective rows can be placed in an array...

Comment: @FaneDuru ,Yes the sent workbook behave correctly. But I am generally avoiding use of helper columns (unless it’s a must).
Anyhow, I will try to use your third answer (on the linked question `Sub FilterByTwoCols()` combined with using of  `CustomViews` and if that also not fixed my issue then I will have to start **Bounty** for my question.

Comment: Now, it depends on how many such rows to remain against how many total rows exist. If a reasonable number, a `Union` Range can be used, then eliminate any filter and hide the `Union` range `EntireRow`... I thought that you want clarifying the `CustomView` issue reliability. Otherwise, you should show all rows then call again the first `Sub`... It will take comparable amount of time against any other solution. You cannot handle discontinuous ranges in arrays.

Comment: No, nothing wrong... Why do you ask this question? The solution you found looks a good one, since it works as you need.